# what's wrong on this f# echo server?

Tags: f#

I've written this f# echo server:

```
open System.Net
open System.Net.Sockets
open System.IO
open System
open System.Text
open System.Collections.Generic

let addr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")
let listener = new TcpListener(addr, 2000)
listener.Start()

let rec loop2(c:TcpClient,sr:StreamReader,sw:StreamWriter)=async {
        let line=sr.ReadLine()
        if not(line=null) then
            match line with
                |"quit"->
                    sr.Close()
                    sw.Close()
                    c.Close()  
                 |_ ->
                    if line.Equals("left") then
                        sw.WriteLine("right")
                        return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
                    sw.WriteLine(line)
                    return! loop2(c,sr,sw)

        else
            sr.Close()
            sw.Close()
            c.Close()   
}

let loop()=async {
while true do
    let c=listener.AcceptTcpClient()
    let d = c.GetStream()
    let sr = new StreamReader(d)
    let sw = new StreamWriter(d)
    sw.AutoFlush<-true
    Async.Start(loop2(c,sr,sw))
}

Async.RunSynchronously(loop())
```

This program can do:

1. echo the client's message
2. when client said 'left',return 'right'
3. when client said 'quit',close the connection

but when I run the programming,when a client sent 'left',get 'right',and sent 'quit',i got this exception:

> not handled exception:  System.ObjectDisposedException: (con't write
>   to closed) TextWriter。 in
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CancellationTokenOps.Start@1192-1.Invoke(Exception
>   e) in .$Control.loop@419-40(Trampoline this,
>   FSharpFunc`2 action) in
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.ExecuteAction(FSharpFunc`2
>   firstAction) in
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Control.TrampolineHolder.Protect(FSharpFunc`2
>   firstAction) in
>   .$Control.-ctor@476-1.Invoke(Object state) in
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state) in
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state,
>   BooleanpreserveSyncCtx) in
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) in
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   in System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() in
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() . .
>   .(press any key to continue)

[Screenshot of program in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iBYe.png)
[Screenshot of exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Ybe.png)

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: what is the exception you get? can you add that info to your question.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exception into the question, instead of using screenshots. Screenshots of the exception don't allow for anyone to Google search the exception text, so it's less helpful. Also, please let us see the entire stacktrace of the exception, instead of just the first line. Seeing the rest of the stacktrace might provide some clues that will let someone figure out what's causing the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, unlike what you might expect from its namesake in imperative languages, `return` in a computation expression doesn't short-circuit. So once the `return!` in the `if line.Equals("right")` returns, ie. after the socket has been closed, the code after the `if` block is run and tries to write to the closed socket. The fix is to put those two lines in an `else`:

```
                if line.Equals("left") then
                    sw.WriteLine("right")
                    return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
                else
                    sw.WriteLine(line)
                    return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
```

As an additional style tip, this whole body can be implemented as a `match`:

```
let rec loop2(c:TcpClient,sr:StreamReader,sw:StreamWriter)=async {
    let line=sr.ReadLine()
    match line with
    | null | "quit" ->
        sr.Close()
        sw.Close()
        c.Close()
    | "left" ->
        sw.WriteLine("right")
        return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
    | _ ->
        sw.WriteLine(line)
        return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is here:

```
if line.Equals("left") then
    sw.WriteLine("right")
    return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
sw.WriteLine(line)
return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
```

If a "left" is received, it writes "right" and then executes nested `loop2`s until a "quit" is received.  Then, after all of that is complete, it tries to write `line` and execute more nested `loop2`s.  Of course, by this point, you have disposed of the connection, hence the exception.

It seems like writing `line` should be in an else block, which would prevent the error:

```
if line.Equals("left") then
    sw.WriteLine("right")
else
    sw.WriteLine(line)
return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
```

Of course, you can also integrate this check with your pattern match.  The example below will handle the null checking and each string option all in one structure.

```
let line = Option.ofObj <| sr.ReadLine()
match line with
|None 
|Some("quit") -> 
    sr.Close()
    sw.Close()
|Some("left") -> 
    sw.WriteLine("right")
    return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
|Some(line) ->
    sw.WriteLine(line)
    return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
```

---

Note that your `async` block is completely useless because you have simply used blocking functions such as `AcceptTcpClient()`, `ReadLine()` and `WriteLine()`.  Putting these functions inside an `async` block does not magically make them asynchronous.  If you want to work asynchronously, it has to be async all the way down.

I'm guessing your objective here is to asynchronously accept clients as they arrive, handling each client asynchronously within a different function.

Most of the .NET API in this area is written in terms of `Task<'T>` rather than the F#-specific `async<'T>`, so I would recommend creating some helper functions:

```
let writeLineAsync (sw:StreamWriter) (text : string) = 
    sw.WriteLineAsync(text).ContinueWith(fun t -> ())
    |> Async.AwaitTask

let readLineAsync (sr:StreamReader) = 
    sr.ReadLineAsync()
    |> Async.AwaitTask

let acceptClientAsync (l : TcpListener) =
    l.AcceptTcpClientAsync()
    |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Then you can create a properly asynchronous version:

```
let rec handleClient (c:TcpClient) (sr:StreamReader) (sw:StreamWriter) =
    async {
        let! line = readLineAsync sr
        match Option.ofObj(line) with
        |None 
        |Some("quit")-> 
            sr.Close()
            sw.Close()
        |Some("left") -> 
            do! writeLineAsync sw "right"
            return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
        |Some(line) ->
            do! writeLineAsync sw line
            return! loop2(c,sr,sw)
    }

let loop() = 
    async {
        let! c = acceptClientAsync listener
        let sr = new StreamReader(c.GetStream())
        let sw = new StreamWriter(c.GetStream())
        sw.AutoFlush <- true
        do! handleClient c sr sw |> Async.StartChild |> Async.Ignore
        return! loop()
    }
```